# Send multiple emails to same user in single SendGrid request

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

```
{
    "headers": {},
    "endpoint": "mail/send",
    "method": "POST",
    "queryParams": {},
    "baseUri": "",
    "body": {
        "from": {
            "name": "Test",
            "email": "test@noreply.com"
        },
        "subject": "Test Send Grid Mail Service",
        "personalizations": [
            {
                "to": [
                    {
                        "email": "user@test.com"
                    }
                ],
                "subject": "Test Send Grid Mail Service",
                "custom_args": {
                }
            },
            {
                "to": [
                    {
                        "email": "user@test.com"
                    }
                ],
                "subject": "Test Send Grid Mail Service",
                "custom_args": {
                }
            }
        ],
        "content": [
            {
                "type": "text/html",
                "value": "Hi"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using this request body to send multiple emails(in this case 2 emails) to the same user but the send grid is sending only one email. Is there a way to send multiple emails to the same user multiple times(in this case 2 emails) in a single send grid request?

Comment: Which API endpoint you are using?

Comment: @AwSnap - mail/send